# How to send the capabilities to Testdroid server

Tags: javascript, ios, appium

[How to send the desiredCapabilities to appium server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZvK1.png)

When i am running the appium facing the error as "You must include a platformName capability".

Can any one tell me how to send the desiredCapabilities  **browserName**, **version**, **javascriptEnable**, **platform** to TestDroid server.

Answer (score 0):

There is official documentation about required capabilities at [docs.bitbar.com](http://docs.bitbar.com/testing/appium/desired-caps/index.html):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("testdroid_username", <username>);
capabilities.setCapability("testdroid_password", <password>);
capabilities.setCapability("testdroid_target", "android");
capabilities.setCapability("testdroid_project", <project nametoshow on Web UI>);
capabilities.setCapability("testdroid_testrun", "Test Run 12/04/2018");
capabilities.setCapability(
   "testdroid_device",
   <The device name that uniquely identifies a device on Bitbar Testing cloud>
);
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(
    new URL("https://appium.testdroid.com/wd/hub"),
    capabilities
);
```